# Can I overload an interface method in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, overloading

I have a data description interface:

```
public interface DataDescription {
     int getId();
}
```

And two implementations:

```
public class DataWithId1 implements DataDescription {
    // ... simple getter impl.
}

public class OtherDataWithId implements DataDescription {
    // ... simple getter impl.
}
```

Now I have this interface:

```
public interface DataProcessor {
    void process(DataDescription data);
}
```

I would like to implement the `DataProcessor` with one class, something like this:

```
public class DataProcessorImpl implements DataProcessor {
    @Override
    public void process(DataDescription data) {
        // Do something...
    }

    public void process(DataWithId1 data) {
        // Do something specific with this type (e.g. directly store in table of database)
    }

    public void process(OtherDataWithId data) {
        // Do something specific with this type (convert to format DataWithId1 and then store in DB)
    }
}
```

And some code to call it:

```
public Main {
    private DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataDescription data = new DataWithId1(1);
        dataProcessor.process(data);
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that the `DataProcessor` caller doesn't have to worry about the data conversion (they have a `DataDescription` and don't have to know about the two types). Additionally I would like to avoid `instanceof` code.

The assumption I've made is that I can overload an interface method like this. I was unable to find proof for this when looking at [section 15.12 of the java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) (which doesn't mean it isn't there...).

Is my assumption about overloading correct? Can I avoid `instanceof`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [*Visitor Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
public interface DataDescription {
    int getId();
    void accept(DataProcessorImpl p);
}

public class DataWithId1 implements DataDescription {
    private final int id;

    public DataWithId1(int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    @Override
    public void accept(DataProcessorImpl p) {
        p.process(this);
    }
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    // ... simple getter impl.
}

public class OtherDataWithId implements DataDescription {
    private final int id;

    public OtherDataWithId(int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    @Override
    public void accept(DataProcessorImpl p) {
        p.process(this);
    }
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return 42;
    }
    // ... simple getter impl.
}
public interface DataProcessor {
    void process(DataDescription data);
}

public class DataProcessorImpl implements DataProcessor {
    @Override
    public void process(DataDescription data) {
        data.accept(this);
    }

    public void process(DataWithId1 data) {
        System.out.println("process(DataWithId1)");
        // Do something specific with this type
        // (e.g. directly store in table of database)
    }

    public void process(OtherDataWithId data) {
        System.out.println("process(OtherDataWithId)");
        // Do something specific with this type
        // (convert to format DataWithId1 and then store in DB)
    }
}

public class Main {
    private static DataProcessor dataProcessor=new DataProcessorImpl();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataDescription data = new DataWithId1(1);
        dataProcessor.process(data);
        data = new OtherDataWithId(100);
        dataProcessor.process(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the `accept` method takes the Impl as an argument. It is possible to use the interface `DataProcessor` here right?

Comment: Well, you can, if you declare all `process` methods in the `DataProcessor` interface. But then, it is too easy to confuse them with the front-end `process` method. The cleanest solution would be to have two interfaces, a *Visitor* interface, used by the `accept` method, and a `DataProcessor` interface for the use site (here, the `main` method). Then, `DataProcessorImpl` may implement both interfaces. So, the `main` method doesn’t have to know about the visitor interface and the `accept` methods don’t have to know about `DataProcessor` (there might be other visitors in the future).

Comment: I think your suggestion for two interfaces is the only way to get this clean. If you don't use two interfaces, all kinds of implementation details go around in the code such as the `DataDescription`s having to know which `DataProcessor` implementations are relevant.

Answer (score 6):

No, this won't work.

There is no overloading in your code. `dataProcessor`'s static type is `DataProcessor`, and `DataProcessor` only has one `process` method.

If you change `dataProcessor`'s static type to `DataProcessorImpl`, you still won't get the desired outcome, since overloading resolution is determined at compile time. Therefore, since the compile time type of `data` is `DataDescription`, `dataProcessor.process(data)` will still invoke `public void process(DataDescription data)` and not `public void process(DataWithId1 data)`.

Comment: So I'm stuck with `instanceof`? That seems to correspond with what I got from my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do if you add the "something specific" into a method in the `DataDescription` interface.

The process() method belongs with each subtype.  You've placed it in the wrong interface.

Let the `DataProcessor` call that method on each `DataProcessor`:

```
public interface DataDescription {
     void somethingSpecific();
}
```

Polymorphism does the work:

```
public class DataProcessorImpl implements DataProcessor {
    @Override
    public void process(DataDescription data) {
        data.somethingSpecific();  // polymorphism does it for you here
    }
}
```

Comment: (A bit late, but) I see how this would work. However, it would require me to break the current design, which basically means that the data objects should be "dumb". In other words, the `DataDescription` objects should not know about the requirements of the `DataProcessor`.

Comment: Five years later?  The proposed design works. I don’t see a down side. Who cares if data objects are dumb?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an abstract class to handle the conversion for you, or alternatively use Java8's default method in the interfaces.

Simply add the keyword 'default' to the method in your interface and give them a body.